# Conflicting argparse Arguments from imported modules

Tags: python-3.x

I am using `pytest-allure`, and I have run tests with the command line argument:

```
pytest -m "group of tests to run."
```

however, the `-m` argument is also shared by an imported module within my code (pyscf):

```
        parser.add_argument('-m', '--max-memory',
                            action='store', dest='max_memory', metavar='NUM',
                            help='maximum memory to use (in MB)')
```

as a result, the code breaks.

How can I resolve this issue, without changing the modules?